# Better way for routing URLs in php

Tags: php, routes

I am not using MVC structure because I find it difficult to handle. So, In my all web-projects I am using step by step straight way. ( I don't know the exact word, but structure using by WordPress. i.e. load files one by one. )

I am redirecting all URL requests to `index.php` file Using `.htaccess`, and get url query from it. Then using that query I load appropriate page.

Site's `index.php` file

```
// load all configuration files, function files here.

$query = ( isset ($_GET['q']) ) ? $_GET['q'] : "index";
if ( !userLoggedIn() ) {
     if ($query == "index") {
          include_once ("pages/index.php");
     } elseif ($query == "signup") {
          include_once ("pages/signup.php");
     } else {
          include_once ("pages/404.php");
     }
} else {
     if (in_array($query, get_list_of_usernames())) {
          include_once ("pages/users.php");
     } elseif () {
          // and so on...
     } else {
          include_once ("pages/404.php");
     }
}
```

Now, My questions,

- Am I doing right with URL routes? OR there is any other more efficient way to do this?
- Is this structure good over MVC, or MVC is better than this?

Comment: there is no problem doing this, but can also use `Switch Case` to better usability.

Comment: @Harpreet, Yes you are right, `Switch Case` is better than nested if. I will use `Switch` now.

Answer (score 1):

Routing is just part of MVC, being part of the controller part. The MVC pattern can theoretically been seen as something different than how you would like to route. MVC is more about how you structure your code.

I once did something like this for a home brew approach for routing. This depends on a controller class having action methods.

You need to have a base class called `Controller` and all your controller classes need to extent it. So the base controller would be `class Controller {}` and any controller could be like `class someController extends Controller { function someAction() {} }` ... Calling the method would be with `http://mysite/someController/someAction`

Index.php:

```
// include callable controllers here
$partsA = explode("?", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); // split querystring
$partsB = explode("/", $partsA[0]); // get url parts
if (count($partsB) < 2)
    die("missing controller in url");
elseif (count($partsB) < 3)
    die("missing action in url");
$className = $partsB[1];
$methodName = $partsB[2];
if (class_exists($className))
    if (!is_subclass_of($className, "controller"))
        die(htmlspecialchars("Class $className doesn't extend controller")); // prevents use of unauthorized classes
    else
        $controller = new $className();
else
    die(htmlspecialchars("Class $className doesn't exist"));

if (!method_exists($controller, $methodName))
    die(htmlspecialchars("Method $methodName doesn't exist"));
else
    $controller->$methodName();
```

Controller.php: (the base controller)

```
class Controller {}
```

Now any controller.... Eg SomeController.php:

```
class someController extends Controller {
    function someAction() {
        echo "test";
    }
}
```

... Calling the `someAction()` method would be done with `http://mysite/someController/someAction` , showing you `test`

Comment: Currently I am not using MVC structure. So, In your opinion which one is better, MVC or Linear (WordPress) ?

Comment: @user1995997 As with all design patterns (eg MVC) it totally depends on what you want to do. If its a small piece of logic, skip the MVC, as MVC is designed for organizing big code and having big parts reusable. You can even use my code that I pasted, and choose NOT TO implement a separate Model and View; and put all code in what I called the Controller. Because what I pasted ins't MVC, but is just the routing part